# creating relative formula in EXCEL 2013 and then applying to rows in same column?

Tags: windows-8

On a Word spreadsheet you just clicked on cell with formula and then used + to drag formula to rows below, each than being updated to that set? of values.   How in Excel do you get the relative formula to rows below?

Answer (score 3):

Just select the cell, and there will be a black square in the bottom right hand corner, drag that down the the next cells